# Django 1.8 admin, blank page displayed after save on popup

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.8.

When I click the + link on a foreign key to add a model I'm redirected to

```
admin/Language/dictionary/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1
```

Edit:[
This is where the problem is, I'm being redirected. 
I've looking at a different project running Django 1.7 and the + link produces a new popup window.]

The page is shown correctly and I can save the model to the database successfully. When I click save I'm redirected to

```
admin/Language/dictionary/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1
```

and the page is blank

I am not using grappelli or any other external app.

How can I fix this ?

Why is the redirect to the same link and not back to the model I clicked the + sign from ?

Edit:
The page I get back has the following code

```
<html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        opener.dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup(window, "7", "Test2");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With a Javascript Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup' of null
```

Comment: Do you get redirected when you click on the + or does the form open in a pop-up? Also, if you open the developer tools, do you see any Javascript errors?

Comment: Thanks, There is a Javascript error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup' of null

Comment: Is it a fresh install or did you have something like Grapelli installed before? How do you run your setup? In debug mode with `runserver` or differently?

Comment: It was a fresh install of Django 1.6, the I upgraded to 1.7 and then 1.8,
I'm using runserver, and debug is set to True.

Comment: I see, there were definitely updates on the Javascript related to the foreign key popup in that time (not sure if it was in 1.7 or 1.8 or both). Did you try clearing the browser cache or using another browser/the inkognito mode? Otherwise you could try removing your Django installation and installing it again (or creating a new virtualenv and installing all your dependencies into it to run the setup from the new env)

Comment: "Do you get redirected when you click on the + or does the form open in a pop-up?"  As far as I can tell it is a redirect, there isn't a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript that creates the popups has changed between `1.6` and `1.8`.
The problem was that the static files that were being served were from Django 1.6. 
I deleted the old static files and made sure that the new files are being served.

If your having the same problem be sure to clear you cached data in your browser, and verify that the static files are in the right location.

Thank you @sthzg for your help.